# How to have an offline Flutter API documentation?

Tags: flutter

Earlier, programming languages used to have their entire API documentation downloadable as a PDF file. But Flutter (and Dart) doesn't seem to have that. All their documentation seems to be [online](https://docs.flutter.dev/).

**Objective:** When I use Android Studio to develop a Flutter app, there are times when I don't want to be connected to the internet. I just want to refer the documentation offline. I can't always use Ctrl+Q or Ctrl+F1, because I might not remember the command. This is where it either helps to have the API documentation as a PDF or if the IDE could list out all the available commands in the same way that it is shown in the Flutter docs website.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm looking for? (apart from downloading every single page of the Flutter/Dart docs website manually or via some automated crawler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

Clone the whole Flutter repository from Github and execute the `docs.sh` script [located here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/dev/bots)
or
Open https://api.flutter.dev/offline/flutter.docset.tar.gz in your browser

*Source : [this Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18723)*